# RuntimeERROR"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql

i having Problem regarding connecting my windowsform with database.When i compile the forms it show"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'"

**Dlayer**

```
public static string ConnectionStr
        {
            
            get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbi"]; }
        }
        public static SqlConnection Getconnection()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr);
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)

            {
                con.Open();
            }
            return con;
        }
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
        <add key="dbi" value=" Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=smproject;Integrated Security=true;"/>
    </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you run, not when you compile?

Comment: i mean when start debuging .

Comment: I have a feeling you are not using the `ConnectionStr` property wherever the exception is being thrown. Can you do two things? Debug your `SqlConnection()` method and let us know what the value of `ConnectionStr` is and then show the code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: In windows forms your life will get easier if you go into project properties, settings, create a settings file if needs be, and put your connection string in there as an application scoped string, then use it in code like `Properties.Settings.Default.YourConnectionStringNameHere`